# unity float and object error in android platform

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

i write this code and i don't know how to fix all error of this code but this code work correctly in pc mode but give error in android mode this is my code :

```
var background : Texture2D;
var splash : Texture2D;
var font : Font;
private var showADPresents = 3.0;
var size = null;

static var virtualScreen : Vector2 = Vector2(800, 600); 

function Update()
{
    showADPresents -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (Application.CanStreamedLevelBeLoaded(1) && Input.anyKeyDown)
        Application.LoadLevel(1);   
}

function OnGUI() 
{
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, Vector3(Screen.width / virtualScreen.x, Screen.height / virtualScreen.y, 1));

    GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(0, 0, virtualScreen.x, virtualScreen.y), splash);

    if (showADPresents > 0)
    {
        var alpha = Mathf.Clamp01(showADPresents);
        var color = Color.white;
        color.a = alpha;
        GUI.color = color;
        GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(0, 0, virtualScreen.x, virtualScreen.y), background);  

        var presentsStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.label);
        presentsStyle.font = font;
        presentsStyle.fontSize = 48;
        size = 300;
        color = Color.black;
        color.a = alpha;
        GUI.color = color;
        GUI.Label(Rect(( virtualScreen.x - size) * 0.5, (virtualScreen.y - size) * 0.5, size, size), "Autodesk Presents:", presentsStyle);
    }   
    else
    {
        var notificationStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.label);
        notificationStyle.font = font;
        notificationStyle.fontSize = 16;
        GUI.color = Color.black;

        var content = null;
        if (Application.CanStreamedLevelBeLoaded(1))
            content = new GUIContent("Click Screen to Continue");
        else
            content = new GUIContent("Loading...");
        size = notificationStyle.CalcSize(content);     
        GUI.Label(Rect((virtualScreen.x - size.x) * 0.5, virtualScreen.y - size.y - 80, size.x, size.y),
            content, notificationStyle);
    }
}
```

and unity give me this error i cant solve this error plz help to me help :'(

http://upload.ghashang.com/images/gm214joveg1z354rkli.jpg

plz Belief i cant solve this error plz help me
plz solve all error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `size` is not a static type. It is dynamic, and because there is no operator for a object subtracted from a float, this error is thrown. You have two options. One, you can cast as a float before you subtract.

```
GUI.Label(Rect(( virtualScreen.x - (float)size) * 0.5, (virtualScreen.y - (float)size) * 0.5, size, size), "Autodesk Presents:", presentsStyle);
```

The other, is to declare `size` as a float or int in the declaration.

```
float size = 0.0f;
//or
int size = 0;
```

However, later you try to reference `size` as though it was a `Rect`, which causes other errors. I would a)declare `size` as a `Rect` b)access the respective members of size. Your code will look like:

```
Rect size;

...

//remove the size = 300; line and replace it with a constructor

GUI.Label(Rect(( virtualScreen.x - size.x) * 0.5, (virtualScreen.y - size.y) * 0.5, size, size), "Autodesk Presents:", presentsStyle);
```

This will solve your issue, and I recommend you read more about [static classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Comment: thank you for help to me and when i change my code unity give me other error plz change this code for me plz change the all of line of this code for me which unity dont give me error plz plz plz help me and change my code thank you friend thank you

Comment: @user3288039 Try searching this site for an answer... There are many questions and most have already been answered

Comment: plz change my code i cant plz change friend just for me :'( :*